# Ejecting SD card takes a long time and CPU usage goes up

Tags: macos, cpu, sd-card, eject

I'm on Mavericks and after I eject most SD cards, it takes a minute or two and process `UASysAgent` is taking 80% of the CPU... quite annoying, does anyone else experience this? Something that can be done about it?

Comment: When it is mounted, try moving the SD card into the list of items to be excluded from Time Machine backups and see if the delay goes away when you dismount it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try disabling Spotlight indexing for the SD card. While the card is inserted go to System Preferences->Spotlight->Privacy->'+' and add the drive.

Comment: This didn't help... still lots of issues when unmounting this card... now I couldn't even do it... it said bash was using it (but it hasn't), anyway I force quit all bash processes and still didn't unmount (didn't say it's because of bash anymore).